# How i can get all pairs prices data?

Tags: web3.py, decentralized-exchange, api

I want to create an arbitrage screener for dex exchanges on all chains, how can I get price tickers for pairs of tokens in different networks? I have an idea that i need to get them under the contract, but I think it’s pretty trivial. Maybe there are some aggregators or api for easy work with this?

Comment: We at Trading Strategy offer API for some hundreds of thousands trading pairs here: https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view - however for high-frequency trading you need to build your own connectors to eliminate any latency and any aggregator is probably too slow for your use case.

Comment: CoinMarketCap/Uniswap API would be a good start.